# Over Riding JavaScript Method when a Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, overriding

I'm trying to get this grid to reload when the button is pressed and to resize based on the users input. Here is what I came up with, but I cant get the grid to load after the button is pressed and prompts are answered. What am I missing here? Am I doing something wrong? Also, what if I wanted the grid to stay the exact same dimensions and only change the number of squares within the grid after the prompts? How would I do that?

```
 <html><body></body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script></html>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').prepend('<div class="container"></div>')

        for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        $('.container').append('<div class="row"></div>')
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        $('.row').append('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
    }

    $('.container').before('<div class="button" style="text-align:center"><p>This Is My Test Button</p></div>')

    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        var userAnswer1 = prompt("How wide would you like the grid?");
        if (userAnswer1 > 50) {
            confirm("Sorry, you can't make a grid wider than 50.");
        } else {
            var userAnswer2 = prompt("How tall would you like the grid?");
            if (userAnswer2 > 50) {
                confirm("Sorry, you can't make a grid taller than 50.");
            } else {
                $('.row').remove();
                for (var i = 1; i < userAnswer1; i++) {
                    $('.container').append('<div class="row"></div>')
                }
                for (var i = 1; i < userAnswer2; i++) {
                    $('.row').append('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('.row').css({
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0',
    });

    $('.row p').css({
        display: 'inline-block',
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0',
        background: 'white',
        border: '1px black solid',
        height: '25px',
        width: '25px',
    }).mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black')
    });

    $('.button p').css({
        width: '436px',
        height: '25px',
        border: '1px solid #18ab29',
    }).mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'gray')
            .mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white')
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: is that an answer a correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few places in your script that I thought were causing issues but it seems the main issue you have is the way you are applying your css. If you get rid of the `$('.row').css({....` and `$('.row p').css({...` blocks and use a style block instead everything should work.

```
<style>
  .row {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .row p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    border: 1px black solid;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
  }

  .row:hover {
    background: #000;
  }
</style>
```

When you apply styles via `$.css()` they only apply to the elements you have in your jQuery object. This means when you delete the elements and add new ones back in you would have to re-apply those styles with your `$.css()` functions. Sometimes this is helpful but in general it is better to use a stylesheet or at least a style block for CSS. That way you can add/remove elements all you want and the styles will still be applied without any extra work on your end.

Comment: That makes sense. I got caught u trying to do everything in javascript. This led me in the right direction and now it works great. Thanks

Comment: suggestion on how i would make it so the dimension of the grid stays the same but the grid amount changes. I tried taking out the dimensions of the .row p and adding dimensions for the .container, but that didnt work.

Comment: That's one spot where you could set height/width with JavaScript. containerWidth/columns=paragraphWidth. Remember you have to apply the styles again every time you add($.append) elements.

Comment: I reposted asking about centering and resizing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168936/centering-resizing-with-css-and-java-script

What do i do with or where do i put this "containerWidth/columns=paragraphWidth"